# Incorporate Record type name on validation rule formula

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I am trying to create a formula that restricts multiple checkboxes from being ticked. User should only be able to tick one checkbox per record. I've managed to create the formula that handles this functionality but I cannot seem to figure out how to add a specific record type for it. Here's what I've Got so far

```
IF (Lighting_Only__c , 1, 0) + 
IF ( Accessories_Only__c , 1, 0) + 
IF ( Accessories_Small_Furniture__c , 1, 0) +
IF ( All_Product_Categories__c , 1, 0)) > 1
```

Can anyone help assist me adding the $recordtype name = 'Dealer' on above formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides summig the result of the field checks, you could add an AND operator to check for the record type:

```
RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Dealer'
```

This way, when the record type is "dealer" and one of the fields is ticked, your validation rule should be triggered.

Also, you should consider getting those fields transformed into a picklist field, since only one of them can be ticket at the same time. This kinda looks like the behavior for a picklist field.

Comment: They're trying to make sure at most *one* box is checked, so your formula isn't quite right.

Comment: I tried that out and unfortunately now it fires even with just 1 checkbox ticked. should only fire when 2 or more checkboxes are ticked

Comment: I reviewed my post, please take a look again. You can reuse your previous formula, I think.